# Is there a way to 'mark' a single row in a table and automatically unmark others?

Tags: mysql, schema, table, features

Is there a way to flag one row in a database table (MariaDB/MySQL mostly, but I just want to know), so that there is only one row in a table that has that flag? If I set that flag (for eg. 'active') for any other row, then the row which currently has the 'active' flag is automatically unset. The idea is to not have to manually unset the older 'active' row when there's going to be a new one. I just insert/update a row with 'active'=1 and it's automatically the only one.

To clarify my intent, I'm not looking for a method of doing this manually - I'm trying to find out if there is a built-in feature in a database system, since this is a pretty common use case. Hence, the post in DBA, instead of SO. I don't even know what tags to use for this question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How will that work? That will just deactivate the currently active row, but I still have to insert/update the next active row. I'm looking for this to happen automatically as I fire my new insert/update.

Comment: I'm not aware of any built in feature for this, but coding such a thing with a trigger is trivial

Comment: @AndrewBrennan Yes, it is trivial, but so is the auto-increment feature. I was wondering if a more recent version of a modern dbms had such a feature and possibly why not.

Comment: MySQL is open source software. If you want a new feature, write it and submit it.

Comment: *pretty common use case*: I would consider this very specific :-) What is the sense of having only a single row active? The only portable way is a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong solution.

Have another table with one row that you keep changing.  It contains the `PRIMARY KEY` of the one marked row.  (Delete the row if you want to have no rows 'marked'.)  `JOIN` the two tables to get the marked rows.